# Are there tutorials and examples of how to interpret PDF documents

Tags: pdf

I am using tools such as [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to interpret PDF files (including text, strokes, glyphs and images) and can access the streams and dictionaries. I am not clear on how these components link together and how to interpret them. In particular I would like to know how to access fonts from the streams.

NOTE: I am not interested in tutorials on how to create PDF documents

Comment: Not sure why the downvote/close. I need tutorials on PDF - I can't find them by searching stack overflow. Questions would seem to be in scope and reasonably clear

Comment: This is about writing programs to process PDF.

Comment: If PHP is acceptable, [this page](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-open-pdi.php) looks like it has some useful library tips (see the comments too).

Comment: Any language binding is acceptable, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably should start from reading [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). It's a huge file but you might read only relevant parts.

To understand font streams you are basically need to read about [TrueType](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6.html) and [Type1](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/T1_SPEC.PDF) font formats (it's not an easy reading either). PDF may contain other font types but TrueType and Type1 are probably most widely used.

Fiddling with fonts might be complicated so you will probably find it easier to use some font library as [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) for extracting information from PDF font streams.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of good article on planetpdf.com and many PDF developers run blogs with useful generic articles. We have run a whole load on our blog (http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/)